# Sometimes images seem to be loading a lower resolution

Tags: image, apache, jpeg, response

Sometimes when I see a lower resolution load before I see the full image. This is not done in jQuery as it also happens when you load the image stand-alone. I have not a single idea how they do this, but I guess it's something server side.

My question is, how would I do this on my own server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images are stored in "progressive" or "interlaced" JPEG format, meaning that the low-res image data is stored before the high-res data (in layman's terms). You can encode any JPEG as interlaced. You can even do it on the server [using imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#interlace).

Here's [Jeff Atwood talking about this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/12/progressive-image-rendering.html).

Comment: This is it! Thanks a lot. I have seen it in Photoshop, though I never understood what it did. Will accept your answer in a bit!